# Скопировать данные из Лист1 в Лист2, при условии, что в первом листе данные постоянно пополняются (увеличиваются)

Tags: excel

Как это лучше сделать, с помощью макроса или с помощью формулы? Или как то один раз выделить и вставить? Вообще суть такая, что у меня есть Лист1, который импортирует данные из CSV, и они все постоянно пополняются и мне все их надо перенести до самого конца на второй лист, где я один из столбцов подправлю с помощью формулы (обрежу текст).

Comment: Как насчет PowerQuery? В смысле, во вкладке Данные создать новый запрос из файла CSV и прямо в запросе указать в какой из колонок какой текст резать... В пять щелчков мышью решить всю задачу

Comment: *Копировать- Вставить* - по Вашему описанию вполне достаточно этих действий. Опишите полнее задачу, прикрепите пример, отображающий проблему.

Comment: Про PowerQuery -классная штука, сейчас понял. Но, я только что обрезал то что хотел, точнее укоротил формат Даты в одном из полей, выделив весь столбец до бесконечности и указал формат без времени. Сработало - при добавлении новых данных в csv, новая строка с укороченной датой отобразилось. Теперь мне надо сгруппировать все одинаковые Даты с одинаковыми именами пользователей. Ладно, это уже отдельноая тема. А то заведу в заблуждение всех.

Comment: Хочу пометить ваш совет, как ответ - не даёт (видимо по времени рано ещё).

Comment: Хорошо, такой вопрос, а я могу перенести все данные на лист2, оставив певоначальным Лист1? Дело в том что данные в дальнейшем будут группироваться по разным принципам и Лист1 должен быть сохранён, так же как и Лист2 потом когда появится еще Лист3.

Comment: Вот какой должна быть последовательность действий: создать пустую книгу, в ней выбрать вкладку Дата, "Создать запрос" из файла CSV. Внутри запроса провести предварительную очистку данных (например, выбросить строки с пустым полем Name или Дата). На основании этого запроса можно создать множество других запросов (например, сгруппировать строки по Name и Дата и тут же подсчитать количество дублей). Любой из запросов (его результат в виде таблицы) можно вставить в любое место любого листа этой книги

Comment: Да. Долго разбирался. Запросы и подключения. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как мне и посоветовали JohnSUN я всё сделал в запросе PowerQuery, там сгруппировал, избавился от лишних данных, поменял тип данных где нужно и т.п. и в листе получил то что надо. Это новый удобный инструмент. Правда я не совсем понял с группировкой power query - При группировке остаются только столбцы, которые группируются, хотя я добавил в группу еще пару нужных столбцов мне столбцов, но при этом должно было перестать группироваться, но работает непонятно как.